# "Visual Studio update required" but its up to date

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 community with Windows 10 UWP SDK running in my computer. Recently I tried to open a project that I imported from another computer and when I launch the solution I get the next error message:

Review Solution Actions 
[image]

Visual Studio update required 
One or more projects require a platform SDK (UAP, Version: 10.0.10586.0) that is either not installed or is included as pat of a future update to Visual Studio.

Install the platform SDK to open these projects.

When I click Ok, I see that all my projects in the solution explorer have the text **(update required)** next to them.

[image]

And when I click it, it takes me to the Windows 10 SDK download page to download an SDK that I have already installed over and over again. I have also repaired the solution more than once. And finally I have reinstalled the Visual Studio 2015 again from scratch.

What can I do to make my project work again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error is very misleading. I spent many precious hours trying to fix it.
If you are certain that your Visual Studio is up to date, you do not need to update nor repair the Visual Studio 2015.

Please follow the next steps:

1. Click Ok on the Error message.
2. Go to your solution explorer and right click on your projects with the (update required) tag.
3. Right click the Project and select the option: "Edit MyProject.csproj"
4. Edit all the appearances to the Windows 10 SDK to a lower version like **10.0.10240.0**

From this:

```c#
<SDKReference Include="WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10586.0">
  <Name>Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>
<SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.10586.0">
  <Name>Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>

<TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

To something like this:

```c#
<SDKReference Include="WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10240.0">
  <Name>Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>
<SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.10240.0">
  <Name>Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>

<TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Repeat for all the projects in your solution, and reload the projects multiple times (VS has a problema to refresh its structure), you have to be patient and probably restart it a couple of times.

And you are good to go!
For more info please review this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Mt148501.aspx#RCUpdate10CSharp

Comment: Encountered this issue out of the blue today. Changing `TargetPlatformVersion` did the trick.
Any idea why this would happen all of a sudden? The error on my VS said I do not have 10.0.10586.0 installed, even though I do. Program&Features shows I have 10586.15 installed.
Also, now I cannot open/create any UWP projects which target 10586. I have to select 10240.

Comment: @siddhant1991 i believe it has to do with Visual Studio wanting to update, but still not having all what it's required to do it. After a few days I found this hack, my VS told me I needed to do a big update and that pretty much fixed everything

Comment: This doesnt look like a correct solution. You are just saying VS to use lower version. this is like downgrading your application to use lower version. There must be a better solution. I have 2 computers and i instaled corect version on both only 1 of them doesnt recognized it for some reason

Comment: @batmaci after doing that and running it you can change it back. Also, you might not be having the same problem, because this error was really specific to a certain version of an update of Vs2015 that was released last year (this error shouldn't be there anymore)

Comment: @BrunoMedina I have this problem on xamarin forms project. I installed latest version 10.0.14393.0 and i get same screenshot although VS installer displays that it is installed. I dont believe that downgrading is a permanent solution. For example, I checked the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\ and there are 4 folders there when I checked each folders only WindowsMobile folder has this highest version. i dont understand why MS doesnt install for other project types. thats why probably It returns "update requred" message

Comment: @batmaci It seems to be related to the same bug, but I don't know it you could get it working with this solution either. What I do know is that after I published this solution I actually received a couple of updates for my VS, those updates also fixed the problem

Comment: thanks @BrunoMedina It is so fine we have stackoverflow for problems like this. How is it that microsoft itself has no reference to this error at all?

Answer (score 2):

I also stumbled upon this error.

There was a Typo in my old installation of Windows Software Development Kit. 
When I opened `Programs and Features`, there was `Windows Software Development Kit 10.1.10586.212`, but the VS2015 project require version `10.0.10586.212`.

So I uninstalled all old ones (there was also `10.0.26624.0`), downloaded new installation `10.0.10586.212` from: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive and it now works without any change in .csproj

Comment: that is actually the solution. I had the same. after uninstalling SDK and reinstalling from the link solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem more correct to go to help/about in visual studio and note the current version of the Visual Studio Tool for Universal Windows Apps and use it. However, there could be change in that version that prevent the app from running. This is a classic compatibility problem with no better solution than to try it and pray. The manifest should show required levels of dependent executables. Another approach would be to rebuild from source and see if it compiles.

This is high level advice. I have such an app I want to build and I will go the route of recreating projects to see if source builds.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem about a week ago, and ended up installing VS again from the Microsoft site. The download that fixed my problem was "Visual Studio Community - with Update 1" from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/C/6FC19DBF-C223-41D0-835A-BD2155BC950D/U1-24720/VSToolsForWindows1C.exe).

Had a few issues with code compatibility afterwards and had to reinstall a few SDKs, but other than that it fixed the "update required" prompts.